# weird behaviour of java while using System.out and System.err

Tags: java

I am printing following output on screen

```
     System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
     System.err.println("Hello World");
     System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
     System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
     System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

and when i try to run my program by pressing **F11** rapidly i am getting mixed output as below:

```
   1447918537647
   Hello World
   1447918537648
   1447918537648
   1447918537648
```

second time

```
   1447918954719
   1447918954720
   1447918954720
   1447918954720Hello World
```

third time

```
   1447919057129
   1447919057130Hello World

   1447919057130
   1447919057131
```

I try to find documentation on this but failed to find answer.